# I need remove a blank space in anchor

Tags: html, image, anchor, space

whan i use img element in anchor I always have a trouble with blank space on bottom...
can someone solve this problem? I don't want that blank space... here is example (i highlight that blank space with red background) http://tinkerbin.com/rNplOZcA

Comment: use this, a {background-color: #d00; border: 0px dashed #008;width:200px;} and also img { display:block; } suggested by @James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the image's display property to `block`

```
img { display:block; }
```

See: http://work.arounds.org/issue/8/mysterious-white-space-gap-under-image-elements/